# Is it possible to reduce the number of MetaStore checks when querying a Hive table with lots of columns?

Tags: hive, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

I am using spark sql on databricks, which uses a Hive metastore, and I am trying to set up a job/query that uses quite a few columns (20+).

The amount of time it takes to run the metastore validation checks is scaling linearly with the number of columns included in my query - is there any way to skip this step? Or pre-compute the checks? Or to at least make the metastore only check once per table rather than once per column?

A small example is that when I run the below, even before calling display or collect, the metastore checker happens once:

```
new_table = table.withColumn("new_col1", F.col("col1")
```

and when I run the below, the metastore checker happens multiple times, and therefore takes longer:

```
new_table = (table
.withColumn("new_col1", F.col("col1")
.withColumn("new_col2", F.col("col2")
.withColumn("new_col3", F.col("col3")
.withColumn("new_col4", F.col("col4")
.withColumn("new_col5", F.col("col5")
)
```

The metastore checks it's doing look like this in the driver node:

```
20/01/09 11:29:24 INFO HiveMetaStore: 6: get_database: xxx
20/01/09 11:29:24 INFO audit: ugi=root    ip=unknown-ip-addr    cmd=get_database: xxx
```

The view to the user on databricks is:

```
Performing Hive catalog operation: databaseExists
Performing Hive catalog operation: tableExists
Performing Hive catalog operation: getRawTable
Running command...
```

I would be interested to know if anyone can confirm that this is just the way it works (a metastore check per column), and if I have to just plan for the overhead of the metastore checks.

Comment: Why not turn off metastore verification? 
hive.metastore.schema.verification false
hive.metastore.schema.verification.record.version false

Comment: Also, what is the spark version? you can check this out: https://kb.databricks.com/metastore/hive-metastore-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised by this behavior as it does not fit with the Spark processing model and I cannot replicate it in Scala. It is possible that it is somehow specific to PySpark but I doubt that since PySpark is just an API for creating Spark plans.

What is happening, however, is that after every `withColumn(...)` the plan is analyzed. If the plan is large, this can take a while. There is a simple optimization, however. Replace multiple `withColumn(...)` calls for *independent* columns with `df.select(F.col("*"), F.col("col2").as("new_col2"), ...)`. In this case, only a single analysis will be performed.

In some cases of extremely large plans, we've saved 10+ minutes of analysis for a single notebook cell.